# Не работает связка py-cpuinfo и pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь получить имя процессора через модуль py-cpuinfo. Через python main.py - все работает отлично.

После чего я пытаюсь скомпилировать программу через Pyinstaller, получаю exe, запускаю его и вижу, что программа ничего не выводит, и вместо этого начинает плодить копии программы в процессах до тех пор, пока нагрузка на ЦП не будет более 100%.

Может быть кто-то ранее сталкивался с подобным?

Вывод название процессора:

```
import cpuinfo

infocpu = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()
ProcessorName = infocpu['brand']

print(ProcessorName)
```

Пробовал 2 варианта:

```
pyinstaller main.py --icon=icon.ico --onefile 
pyinstaller main.py --icon=icon.ico
```

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы добавить минимальный пример с проблемой и скрипт запуска для pyinstaller, который собираете? Я к примеру [собирал](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/build_exe/pyinstaller_example) через `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

Comment: @gil9red добавил

Comment: У меня при запуске после сборки ругнулся на `ImportError: No module named 'cpuinfo'`

Comment: Поменял на `pyinstaller --hiddenimport=cpuinfo --onefile -F main.py` и помогло. Странно, запустил скрипт и ничего -- просто висит скрипт :) Можно создать багу на https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues

Comment: @gil9red ругался потому что нужно сперва pip install pu-cpuinfo :)

Comment: @gil9red да, он висит, но если зайди в диспетчер задач, то там каждую секунду будет новый процесс создаваться

Comment: Ругался собранный в exe, а установку через pip сделал ранее. Не знаю почему pyinstaller не зацепил cpuinfo, вот поэтому и пришлось указать ему на модуль

Answer (score 0):

```
from cpuinfo import get_cpu_info
import multiprocessing


def support_virtualization():
    '''this function return name cpu
    and flags cpu'''
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    a = get_cpu_info()
    brand = a.get('brand')
    flags = a.get('flags')
    return brand, flags
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А как ответ связан с вопросом?

Comment: @gil9red ключевой вызов: добавить mp.freeze_support() (если cpuinfo использует multiprocessing внутри, то это может помочь при запуске exe, собранного с помощью pyinstaller — то что процессы плодятся намекает что это так)